# Is it possible to export the texture shown here, after I have used nodes to change the color?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, export

I took this original brown hat texture and used nodes to make it black. Is it possible for me to export the new black version of the hat, instead of the original brown image??

[image: I Used nodes to turn down the brightness]

[image: Original Texture is Brown]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1):

One way I know of is by baking the modified texture to a new image.

Begin by creating a blank image of the same dimensions as the texture

[image]

My original image:
[image]

My image modified by nodes:
[image]

To bake, make sure your render engine is set to **cycles**.

Find the bake tab under render properties and uncheck lighting influences (direct and indirect) to make sure lighting is not baked into your texture and only the node modifications are.

[image]

Select the object the texture is on, the last node in the tree that you want to save edits of, and the blank image you made earlier. Make sure the blank image is selected last, ie, is the active object.
In my case, I select the plane, the RGB curves node, and finally the blank image texture.

[image]

Click "Bake" under the bake tab. Wait for it to process.

Finally, load up your previously blank image in the image editor and you should see

[image]

Make sure you save this image before closing the scene.

This [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Aj006df-boI) could help.

There are many other tutorials about specific settings of baking that you can look into but I find that this is the simplest method that gets the job done.